# Membership form submit button goes to 404 not found error

Tags: civimember

We have a membership form that has been working for several years. For some reason we are now getting a 404 not found error when submitting the form.

The url for the error 404 page is:

https://---.org/membership/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact

We don't update CiviCRM very often. Wordpress updates itself periodically.

Wordpress 5.5.1
CiviCRM 5.15.1

I've also tried deactivating every plugin, and using a different theme, and the problem still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are on wordpress 5.5 it s mandatory to upgrade civicrm to 5.26 or more (5.28.x preferred) else all your front end civi forms will not work

Ref: https://civicrm.org/blog/kcristiano/civicrm-526-and-wordpress-important-notice